# How to get all the sheetnames from Excel using Epplus?

Tags: c#, epplus

Hi I am not sure how I can achieve it. How I can get the sheet names of an excel file using Epplus? I tried the below code but its not giving the output.

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(currentDir + @"/seo easier/" + "Backlinks_With_Logins.xlsx");
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
  package.Workbook.Worksheets.Select(x => x.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I achieved it with the following code.

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(currentDir + @"/seo easier/" + "Backlinks_With_Logins.xlsx");
var excel = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo);

foreach (var worksheet in excel.Workbook.Worksheets)
{
    this.comboBoxExcelSheetNames.Items.Add(worksheet.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work but it doesn't seem like you've put any code to output the names of the worksheets. Try adding a return statement like this:

```
return package.Workbook.Worksheets.Select(x => x.Name);
```

Or assigning it to a variable and then outputting that:

```
var worksheets = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Select(x => x.Name);
foreach (var sheet in worksheets) Console.WriteLine(sheet);
```